# Keep google score after new wordpress site?

Tags: wordpress

I'm currently helping a friend to the family updating there website from the stone age. It's currently a WordPress site that I'm going to remove and replace with a new one.

The thing is that the site is the first result from google (it's an unusual name). And I don't really want to destroy that because from Google it links to stuff on the site (like google does).

Anything here I need to think of, so I don't destroy this? I was trying to figure out what to search for but only found SEO stuff. And that's not really what I'm looking for.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The things you need to take into consideration are SEO stuff ;)

First, if the term that's giving you the first result in Google is the name of the website/brand, it's unlikely that you'll destroy that enough to lose that ranking, especially if it's an unusual word, like you said.

If you're concerned about regular search terms that might be sending traffic to the site, make sure the URL structure stays the same as it is now. That way if other websites are linking into your site, you won't suddenly have broken links. Try to keep content in place that could be contributing to the current rankings, like headings, filenames, and paragraph text.